# TypeError: jQuery.getJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

I'm new to node.js and python web server. In `app.py` I have set up a python web server with sanic and a function. The server starts fine and I can retrieve the result of the function on http://localhost:8000/ successfully.

request.js:

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');

jQuery.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/', 
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
)
```

But when running node request.js in the terminal I get the following error:

```
TypeError: jQuery.getJSON is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/temp/request.js:3:8)
```

I tried several options to integrate jQuery. Where is the bug?

Comment: jquery in node? https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery#node suggests you are doing it wrong - *For jQuery to work in Node, a window with a document is required*

Comment: [Several dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=node+getJSON+site:stackoverflow.com)